# ODP.net data and toad data difference

Tags: c#, .net, toad, oracle

I have a case where data being logged by my app which uses ODP.net is logging 0.99999954368250 where as when I query the same data using toad it shows 0.99999999999999, not sure what's causing this

I checked data types of table and c#, table uses NUMBER without any limit and c# uses double. Since the difference is after 6-7 digits I believe from NUMBER to double conversion is not causing it.

Comment: There are numbers that can easily be represented base 10 but that don't have an equivalent as a .net base 2 `double`

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point arithmetics.